# Choosing the appropriate coding expression for a given job

Tags: vector, common-lisp

Common Lisp provides many flexible coding options for achieving a given result. However, it is sometimes difficult to choose the best approach. For example, the following vector expressions all produce the same result in different ways.

```
(defparameter objects (list 1 2 3))

(apply #'vector objects)

(coerce objects 'vector)

(make-array (length objects) :initial-contents objects)

(read-from-string (format nil "#~S" objects))
```

Of course, some expressions are more flexible than others, depending on the required output; but for a given output as above, what criteria are useful for deciding which to use?

Comment: In general, *your specific criteria.*  Things like: Does it actually do what it is supposed to do?  Is it maintainable?  Does it have adequate performance?  Does it scale satisfactorily? Does it reasonably conform to the coding style the shop is already using, assuming that style is already adequate?

Comment: In other words, *whatever **your** definition of **best** is.*  Or, to put it another way, *"Does this meet our specific functional and non-functional requirements?"* (assuming those are solid).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `(apply #'vector objects)` is subject to the usual limitations of [`APPLY`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm), which is that `objects` shouldn't hold more than [`CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_call_a.htm) elements. This is bad style even when you have only a few arguments.
- [`COERCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_coerce.htm) is great: not only it performs the job, it also conveys the intent very well. However, you won't be able to give additional parameters for the resulting vector (e.g. fill-pointer, etc.); you cannot convert nested lists into matrices.
- [`MAKE-ARRAY`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_ar.htm) gives you full control over the resulting array: adjustability, fill-pointer, dimensions, element-type, displacement.
- [`READ-FROM-STRING`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_fro.htm) is a big **no** for data conversion, in general. In terms of useless computations, this approach is the Rube Goldberg's version of `coerce`. It also comes with a lot of security concerns, unless you are 100% sure about what the string contains. Here, you create the string yourself, but if your data contains any value for which another part of the code redefined [`PRINT-OBJECT`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_pr_obj.htm), the code might break.